# How to calculate the length of a array in this case

Tags: javascript

I am geting the following response from a Ajax call

```
[
    {
        "orderjson": "[{\"contact_phone_no\":\"9866545438\"},{\"contact_phone_no\":\"9866545438\"}]"
    }
]
```

I am trying to take the length of orderjson this way .

```
var data = 

    [
    {
        "orderjson": "[{\"contact_phone_no\":\"9866545438\"},{\"contact_phone_no\":\"9866545438\"}]"
    }
]

  console.log(JSON.stringify(data[0].orderjson.length));
```

But when i do so i am geting its length as 69 wheer as it is 2 .

Please tell me how to resolve this

Comment: It looks like you're double-encoding the returned JSON, which means the child property is being encoded as one large string. You should change the response format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using JSON.stringify you're transforming the JSON into a string then the length call gives you the length of the resulting string.

Just do:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(data[0].orderjson).length)
```

and it should work.

You need JSON.parse because the orderjson content is a string.